# Sending a class through json post

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http-post

How can a NSObject class be sent through json post?

Example:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *Value1;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *Value2;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *Value1;
@end
```

In another file that implements the TestClass:

```
TestClass *test = [[TestClass alloc]init];
test.Value1 = @"First";
test.Value2 = @"Second";
test.Value3 = @"Third";
```

.....

How can the test object be sent?

Comment: Just for the record - it is not the class that you're trying to serialise, but an _instance_ of the class. Luckily, that is much simpler. Also, normal naming conventions would have property (and method) names beginning with lower case.

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20996601/730807 I am using that way and it works so well and it will suit your needs too.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Carl points out you have to [convert it first to a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548429/convert-an-ios-objective-c-object-to-a-json-string), and then send it as a parameter on your POST request. Be aware that the back-end defines how your data should be send for requests. But this is the most common way of doing it.