# Passing iOS objects to React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-native-module

I have a object `employeeList` which contains objects `employee` and then each employee object has a `person` object and `address` object in it and `person and address` both contain `NSString` properties and well as a some function e.g.  `calculateAge()`.

I want to pass this `employeeList` object from the Native side to the react native side but it come up as null, it is because it RN bridge will only send privimite data types.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#argument-types

What is the best way to convert employeeList to a JSON object or a nested map so that it can be viewed in the RN side?

Comment: Have a look all answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548429/convert-an-ios-objective-c-object-to-a-json-string Might help you. Basicaly use a library to do it.

Comment: I think you need to convert your person and address objects to dictionaries, and resolve them back to the JS side.

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks for the comments, Is there any quick way to do it? ( Besisdes using a library, I see RCTConvert does the opposite thing)

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** send through the bridge `objects` with nested functions as properties of the same `object`. But you are able to send native **functions/methods**  declared in a self built module in `Objective-C` or `Swift`.

I would recommend you to export a function `calculateAge()` in the native module. This function receives as parameter the JSON object `employee` a returns the desired age of this employee using **callbacks or emitting events** 
although I would use a construction with **[Promises](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#promises)** for that. Also this function could be called when you want on the JS side. However write this kind of function on a native module would make no sense because you can perform the same logic on the JS side.

Export a function in a native module would be useful if the logic needs extra data that only runs on the native side.

Finally make sure that you export an `object (NSDictionary)` with string **keys** and **values** of any type from [this list](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#argument-types). So you need to convert the object `employeeList` to a JSON Object and delete nested functions from it in order to avoid compatibility problems.