# simple way to map a json collection response into swift object class

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Ive tried a lot of libraries, Alamofire, JsonHelper, ObjectMapper etc..., but unfortunately, Ive coundn't map a json collection response into an object class.
Im developing an IOS 8 App with swift 1.2 and xcode 6.3, and two classes of my model are:

Club.swift

```js
class Club { 

    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var imageUrl: String = ""
    var hasVip: Bool = false
    var desc: String = ""
    var location: [Location] = []

}
```

Location.swift

```js
class Location {

    var country: String = ""
    var city: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var zip: String = ""
    var underground: [String] = []

}
```

I have another class to request to my API:

apliClient.swift

```js
class ApiClient {

    var clubs = [Club]?()


    func getList(completionHandler: ([JSON]) -> ()) {
        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://api.com/v1/clubs")
        let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer R01.iNsG3xjv/r1LDkhkGOANPv53xqUFDkPM0en5LIDxx875fBjdUZLn1jtUlKVJqVjsNwDe1Oqu2WuzjpaYbiWWhw==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
        let request = manager.request(mutableURLRequest)

        request.responseJSON { (request, response, json , error) in
            if (json != nil){
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                if let data = jsonObj["hits"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                    completionHandler(data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I think, there is a simple way to mapping objects in swift. I would like to know, how I can return the completionHandler(data) converted into a [Club] object?

**let data** = jsonObj["hits"].arrayValue as [JSON]?  **is**

```js
[{
  "_id" : "5470def9e0c0be27780121d7",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/5470def9e0c0be27780121d7_180.png",
  "name" : "Mondo",
  "hasVip" : false,
  "location" : {
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f_180.png",
  "name" : "Teatro Kapital",
  "hasVippler" : false,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "Atocha, 125",
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/api-static\/clubs\/540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b_180.png",
  "name" : "Charada",
  "hasVippler" : false,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "La Bola, 13",
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}]
```

Comment: create an `init` in `Club` that takes a `JSON` object and then loop through the array elements and make a `Club` object out of each element, append that element to an array and pass that array through the completion block.

Comment: why not using SwitfyJSON and Alamofire?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the `ObjectMapper` library that you mentioned above. Simply create the `Club` class and make sure it implements the `Mappable` protocol. Then you can use ObjectMapper as follows to map the data:

`let clubs = Mapper<Club>().mapArray(JSONString)`

Full disclosure: I am the author of ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0):

For objective-c try [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) it can be what you are looking for...
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771854/1787109) you can find some more example of using it

note this about swift (from JSONModel's GitHub page):

> Swift works in a different way under the hood than Objective-C. Therefore I can't find a way to re-create JSONModel in Swift. JSONModel in Objective-C works in Swift apps through CocoaPods or as an imported Objective-C library.

---

**Update:**

Check ups this blog post from apple about ***Working with JSON in Swift***
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 2.0, it is now possible, simple copy your json to http://www.json4swift.com and the swift models with entire key-value mapping will be auto generated, all you need to do is instantiate the models by passing either array or dictionary out of your Json.

Comment: ok, this is good to generate the model of large json response. but how can  we map the response to these class models.

Comment: there are convenience methods already present in those models, once you get the response dictionary or array of dictionary, simply pass it to those convenience models and you'll be returned with the mapped models