# How do i convert following response to json

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, data-conversion

[image]
Image shows the response, need to convert this into json, below is the structure of response am getting.
I received the following response on **`xcode`** (Objective-C).

How can I convert this to `JSON`-compatible on *Objective-C* itself?

```
{
"abc" = "lmn";
"def" = "pqr";
object =     {
    "object1" =         {
        obj = 1;
        obj2 = ABC;
    };
    "object2" =         {
        obj3 = 0;
        obj4 = LMN;
    };
};
```

Comment: @Mamun No its not in JSON, so can't use JSON.parse()

Comment: Can i convert this response into json format using xcode?

Comment: [Serialize and Deserialize Objective-C objects into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172001/serialize-and-deserialize-objective-c-objects-into-json)

Comment: Please post some code that you have of how you are receiving this and how do you print it. From the way it is printed it looks that it have been parsed already.

Comment: @battlmonstr updated above with image

Comment: Please don't use images with code, type them in your question yourself.